# How can I check status of hover on a pseudo-element inside a setTimeout timer? Timer Couses error

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout

I want to check status of hover of an element inside a timer, however on this line I receive an error:

```
if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover'))
```

This is the error :

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

When i remove setTimeout timer error is vanished.

It seems inside that timer `$(this).nextAll('ul:first')` returns an empty element. I don't know why!!

What is wrong about that timer & how fix it?

**With Timer - has error :**

```js
$(".sf-with-ul").hover(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeInUpSmall");
}, function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('Timer End');
  if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover')) {
    console.log('1');
  } else {
    console.log('2');
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeInUpSmall");
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  }
}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.sf-with-ul + ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-ps2id-api="true" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu animated fast fadeInUpSmall" style="display: block;">
  <li id="menu-item-1281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1281"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/active-your-cards/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Activate Your Cards</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1271"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/card-balance/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Check Cards Balance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Without Timer - There is no error :**

```js
$(".sf-with-ul").hover(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeInUpSmall");
}, function() {
  if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover')) {
    console.log('1');
  } else {
    console.log('2');
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeInUpSmall");
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  }
});
```

```css
.sf-with-ul + ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-ps2id-api="true" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu animated fast fadeInUpSmall" style="display: block;">
  <li id="menu-item-1281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1281"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/active-your-cards/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Activate Your Cards</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1271"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/card-balance/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Check Cards Balance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Two suggestions... this question could really be simplified. There's a lot of irrelevant code up there that makes it hard to see the actual problem. Also, _you_ don't get votes... your questions and answers do. And sometimes folks make mistakes. Don't take it so personally.

Comment: setTimeout makes `this` not what you think it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the basic concept that setTimeout executes in widow scope so when you do it, the `this` is the window. So store the reference to the element outside of it.

```
...
function () {
  var elem = $(this)
  window.setTimeout( function () {
    console.log(elem, this)
    var hovered = elem.nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover')
  }), 1000)
}
...
```